# CPU warning every time I boot

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, cpu

Every single time I boot my Linux distro I get a message that says:

```
RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!
```

Is this a serious security issue?

Comment: No, unless you're a large hosting provider offering shared VPS.

Comment: You are unlikely to be affected by the "vulnerability" but you can eliminate the warning message by adding `retbleed=off ` to the grub command line.